# Где подправить open_basedir?

Tags: php, linux, apache, debian, администрирование

Debian8 с VestaCP
phpinfo показывает такие данные (закрыто доменное имя)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде как пишут что надо править httpd.conf но при поиске в системе он находит их несколько:

```
/usr/local/vesta/install/rhel/5/monit/httpd.conf
/usr/local/vesta/install/rhel/5/httpd/httpd.conf
/usr/local/vesta/install/rhel/6/httpd/httpd.conf
/usr/local/vesta/install/rhel/7/monit/httpd.conf
/usr/local/vesta/install/rhel/7/httpd/httpd.conf
```

Может это не те файлы. Где задаётся локальное значение open_basedir? Потому что Master Value справа пустое (no value)

Comment: open_basedir - это параметр не Apache, а PHP. Задаётся, соответственно, в настройках PHP.

Comment: в настройках сервера php.ini он закомментирован и в локальном /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini тоже

Answer (score 2):

open_basedir задаётся в конфиге сайта с шаблонами весты для сайта типа hosting и basedir, при этом в конфиге в блоке `<Directory /home/admin/web/****>` прописывается параметр типа

```
php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/web/***/
```

Конфиги веста генерирует в папку пользователя, например для пользователя admin

```
/home/admin/conf/web/httpd.conf
```

Можно отредактировать конкретный конфиг конкретного сайта, но при пересоздании пользователя или WEB из панели эти правки затруться из шаблона. Лучшее решение это оттестить свои правки и потом отредактировать шаблоны конфигов, которые лежат тут

```
/usr/local/vesta/data/templates/web/
```

Важное уточнение, редактирование через SFTP сторонними редакторами в Windows могут сломать шаблон, по этому лучше это делать через mcedit, nano или другими консольными редакторами.